# $R$ is a commutative ring such that for any ideal $I$ and $a\in I$, there is an ideal $J$ such that $IJ = (a)$. Show ideals are finitely generated.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals, finitely-generated

So we are given $R$ is a commutative ring such that for every nonzero ideal $I$ of $R$ and element $a\in I$, there is a unique ideal $J$ such that $IJ = (a)$. We are supposed to show that this means every ideal is finitely generated.

This is the jist of what I have so far. Let $I$ be an ideal and $a\in I$. Then there is some $J$ such that $(a) = IJ$. This means that $a = x_iy_i + \cdots + x_ny_n$ for $x_i\in I$ and $y_i\in J$. Then our professor told us that we should show $I' = Rx_1 + \cdots Rx_n$ is equal to $I$. He also said that to show this we should show that $I'J = IJ$. Showing $I' \subseteq I$ is simple, and from this it follows that $I'J \subseteq IJ$. I was also able to show that $I'J \supseteq IJ$, so $I'J = IJ$.

But now I don't see how this implies that $I' = I$. Any thoughts?

Edit: I found a similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2125467/r-be-an-integral-domain-and-i-j-be-ideals-such-that-ij-is-a-principal-idea?rq=1), but that requires that $R$ be an integral domain, and we are not given that in this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$J $ must also be a nonzero ideal, but then $IJ=I'J=(a)$, and $R $ is commutative so $JI=JI'=(a)$. The assumption was that this $J $ was unique, so the $I $ must be unique when applying this condition to $J $. Hence $I=I'$.

Comment: beat me to it noah. Good to see you back :)

Comment: @AndresMejia Thanks

Comment: Ah of course! Thanks Noah! :)